# Finding a Linear fractional Transformation that maps $A$ to $B$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I wonder if anyone has an idea how to construct a Linear fractional transformation that maps $A=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z-i|\geq 1\}$ to the unit disc $B=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|\leq 1\}$.

It is not obvious to me how to find such a linear fractional transformation that maps $A$ directly to $B$. So, my idea I have is to find an "easy to find" linear fractional transformation (say $f$) that maps $A$ to some region (say $C$), and then find another linear fractional transformation (say $g$) that maps the region $C$ to $B$. Then, the linear fractional transformation I am looking for, will be just $gof$. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you find one from $\{|z|\ge 1\}$ to $B$?

Comment: @John: I think $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ does the job. Then, I don't know how to use this in my problem?

Comment: First find one from $\{|z-i|\ge 1 \}$ to $\{|z|\ge 1\}$. Then $\{|z|\ge 1\}$ to $B$.

Comment: @John: Is the function that maps the region $\{|z-i|\geq 1\}$ to $\{|z|\geq 1\}$ the one defined by $g(z)=z-i$? Therefore the function I am looking for will be $(fog)(z)=f(g(z))=f(z-i)=\frac{1}{z-i}$. Please let me know whether I am doing it right. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @John: Thanks for your help! I appreciate it a lot!